# how can I plot on colorbar python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

How can I plot on a colorbar?

If for example I create a colorbar that range from 0,1 and I want to mark a with a red line the values 0.3 and 0.8 , how can I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I managed to find the answer

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, colorbar

data = [[0.0,0.2],[0.5,1.0]]
imshow(data)

cb = colorbar()
cb.ax.plot([0,1],[cb.norm(0.3),cb.norm(0.3)],'r')
cb.ax.plot([0,1],[cb.norm(0.8),cb.norm(0.8)],'r')
```

Comment: I added a few lines to make your answer runnable.